# php Объединение массивов без повторений элементов

Tags: php, массивы, объединение

Есть два массива

Первый:

```
    Array
(
    [0] => a
    [1] => b
    [2] => c
    [3] => d
)
```

Второй:

```
    Array
(
    [0] => a
    [1] => b
    [2] => c
    [3] => e
)
```

Подскажите, как объединение первый и второй массив чтоб получилось:

```
    Array
(
    [0] => a
    [1] => b
    [2] => c
    [3] => d, e
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант, смотрите в сторону [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-map.php)

```
$result = array_map(function($a, $b){ 
                    if($a === $b) return $a;
                    return [$a, $b];
              }, $first, $second);
```

Comment: Подскажите, а как можно объединить больше 2х массивов, например array(a, b, c) + array(a, b, d) = array(a, b, array(c, d));
array(a, b, array(c, d)) + array(a, b, e) = array(a, b, array(c, d, e));
И на практике таких массивов больше сотни. Сам недавно начал изучать языки, пока не могу понять как это сделать

Comment: @dkiii у вас все равно по два массива объединяется. А вот чтобы вложенность учитывать, то `return [$a, $b]` можно  заменить на `return array_merge((array)$a, (array)$b)`, но это только на один уровень вложенности даст эффект. В противном случае, у вас вообще другая задача чем в вопросе, и нет смысла их смешивать тут.

Comment: а если у вас 100 пар массивов, то соответственно нужен цикл по этим парам.