# php Объединение большого количества массивов в один без повторов

Tags: php, массивы, объединение

Есть массив в котором лежит около сотни подмассивов.

Задача объединить эти подмассивы и убрать повторяющиеся элементы.

Например:

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => a
            [1] => b
            [2] => c
            [3] => d
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => a
            [1] => b
            [2] => c
            [3] => e
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => a
            [1] => b
            [2] => f
            [3] => e
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => a
            [1] => g
            [2] => f
            [3] => e
        )

)
```

Результат:

```
    Array
(
    [0] => a
    [1] => b,g
    [2] => c,f
    [3] => d,e
)
```

Comment: Какие-нибудь попытки достичь желаемого результата предпринимались?

Comment: Попытки были придумать схему по достижению результата. Дошел до мысли взять нулевой массив, к нему добавить [1], а вот как теперь взять результат [0+1] и добавить к нему [2], и тоже самое сделать с 3, 4..., не могу понять. гугл не помог

Comment: Создай массив пустой. Туда добавь 1. К нему 2. И т.д., пока не получишь желаемого результата. Проверяй на наличие через in_array(); Используй только 1 цикл на 2 массива, чтобы идентификатор не путался.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [php Объединение массивов без повторений элементов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/827891/php-%d0%9e%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%b7-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2)

Comment: Darik Saifutdinov, спасибо, буду пробовать

Comment: @Эдуард подходы к решению могут быть довольно разными. для случая с двумя и более входящими массивами. что собственно и демонстрируется  в моих ответах. Так что я бы не стал говорить, что это дубликат. да схожи по сути, но разные по решению.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В прошлом вашем вопросе была два массива, поэтому сравнивались два элемента. В этот же раз следует сравнивать большее число элементов, поэтому и решение будет другим, с использованием `array_unique`, к примеру. Распаковка/упаковка массива в параметры функций тоже будет весьма уместна.

Исходные данные

```
$data = [
          ['a','b','c','d'],
          ['a','b','c','e'],
          ['a','b','f','e'],
          ['a','g','f','e']
    ];
```

решение

```
$result = array_map(function(...$x){ return array_unique($x); },  ...$data);
print_r($result);
```

результат

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
            [0] => a 
        )
    [1] => Array (
            [0] => b
            [3] => g
        )
    [2] => Array (
            [0] => c
            [2] => f
        )
    [3] => Array (
            [0] => d
            [1] => e
        )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать так, но думаю это не лучший способ:

```
$res = [];
foreach ($array as $ar) {
    foreach ($ar as $k => $a) {
        $res[$k][] = $a;    
    }
}
array_walk($res, function(&$val) { $val = implode(',', array_unique($val));});

print_r($res);
```

Результат:

```
Array
(
    [0] => a
    [1] => b,g
    [2] => c,f
    [3] => d,e
)
```